# I'm trying to extend a Java program given to us at Uni, and I can't get the program to use the methods in the new class

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

So, firstly I'm a pretty amateur Java programmer and it's just one module and then it's over.

The criteria is to override the predefined 'about()' command in our TurtleGraphics program.

I can get it to work if I put the override in the GUI class with everything else, but when I try to create an 'ExtendedTurtleGraphics' class and try and call it, it just doesn't do anything, doesn't throw an error, just does nothing.

**This is the Extended Class and Content**

```
public class ExtendedTurtleGraphics extends TurtleGraphics {
TurtleGraphics TG = new TurtleGraphics();
theTurtle turtle = new theTurtle();
String Command;
@Override
public void about() {
    super.about();
    System.out.print("Testing..."); //Working!
    Command = "backward 100";
    turtle.getCommand(Command, this);
    Command = "penDown";
    turtle.getCommand(Command, this);
    Command = "forward 200";
    turtle.getCommand(Command, this);
    Command = "turnright 120";
    turtle.getCommand(Command, this);
    Command = "forward 50";
    turtle.getCommand(Command, this);
}

/*@Override
public void circle(int radius) {
    super.circle(radius);

    }*/
}
```

**This is the whole GUI class, the about section follows on**

```
public class myGUI extends JPanel{

    static JTextField commandbox;
    boolean isSaved = false;
    TurtleGraphics TG = new TurtleGraphics();
    theTurtle turtle = new theTurtle();
    TurtleGraphics ETG = new ExtendedTurtleGraphics();
    public myGUI()
    {
        JFrame MFrame = new JFrame();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(Color.white);
        commandbox = new JTextField(5);
        MenuBr mb = new MenuBr();
        MFrame.setJMenuBar(mb);
        MFrame.add(commandbox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        commandbox.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
        MFrame.add(TG);
        MFrame.setSize(640, 480);
        MFrame.setVisible(true);
        MFrame.validate();
        MFrame.repaint();
        ExtendedTurtleGraphics ETG;

    }
    public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage, titleBar, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    class MenuBr extends JMenuBar implements ActionListener {
        JMenu fileMnu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem newMnuI = new JMenuItem("New");
        JMenuItem openMnuI = new JMenuItem("Load");
        JMenuItem saveMnuI = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem closeMnuI = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenu helpMnu = new JMenu("Help");
        JMenuItem aboutMnuI = new JMenuItem("About");


        MenuBr() {
            add(fileMnu);
            fileMnu.add(newMnuI);
            fileMnu.add(openMnuI);
            fileMnu.add(saveMnuI);
            fileMnu.add(closeMnuI);
            newMnuI.addActionListener(this);
            openMnuI.addActionListener(this);
            saveMnuI.addActionListener(this);
            closeMnuI.addActionListener(this);
            add(helpMnu);
            helpMnu.add(aboutMnuI);
            aboutMnuI.addActionListener(this);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == newMnuI) {
                TG.reset();
                TG.turnLeft(90);
                TG.clear();
                TG.penDown();
            }
            if (e.getSource() == openMnuI) {
                if (isSaved == true) {
                    String loadName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Load File Path (Excluding .png) :");
                    loadName = loadName + ".png";
                    try {
                        BufferedImage loadedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(loadName));
                        TG.setBufferedImage(loadedImage);
                    } catch (IOException exception) {
                        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
                    }
                } else if (isSaved == false) {
                    int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Save before loading?", "Are you sure?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    System.out.println(n);
                    if (n == 0) {
                        Graphics g = TG.getGraphicsConext();
                        BufferedImage i = TG.getBufferedImage();
                        String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Save File Path (Excluding .png): ");
                        fileName = fileName + ".png";
                        File file = new File(fileName);
                        try {
                            ImageIO.write(i, "png", file);
                        } catch (IOException el) {
                            el.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String loadName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Load File Path (Excluding .png) :");
                        loadName = loadName + ".png";
                        try {
                            BufferedImage loadedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(loadName));
                            TG.setBufferedImage(loadedImage);
                        } catch (IOException exception) {
                            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
                        }
                    } else if (n == 1) {
                        String loadName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Load File Path (Excluding .png) :");
                        loadName = loadName + ".png";
                        try {
                            BufferedImage loadedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(loadName));
                            TG.setBufferedImage(loadedImage);
                        } catch (IOException exception) {
                            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (e.getSource() == saveMnuI) {
                isSaved = true;
                Graphics g = TG.getGraphicsConext();
                BufferedImage i = TG.getBufferedImage();
                String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Path (Excluding .png): ");
                fileName = fileName + ".png";
                File file = new File (fileName);
                try{
                    ImageIO.write(i, "png", file);
                } catch (IOException el) {
                    el.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (e.getSource() == closeMnuI) {
                if (isSaved == true)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Save before quitting?", "Are you sure?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    System.out.println(n);
                    if (n == 0)
                    {
                        Graphics g = TG.getGraphicsConext();
                        BufferedImage i = TG.getBufferedImage();
                        String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Path (Excluding .png): ");
                        fileName = fileName + ".png";
                        File file = new File (fileName);
                        try{
                            ImageIO.write(i, "png", file);
                        } catch (IOException el) {
                            el.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else if (n == 1)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**This is the about section**

```
        if (e.getSource() == aboutMnuI) {
            ETG.clear();
            ETG.about();
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("FilePath");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Turtle Graphics\nJoe Bloggs\n4FS1\nOOP Assessment 2020", "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
            }
        }
    }
    class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == commandbox) {

                String command = commandbox.getText();
                isSaved = false;
                turtle.getCommand(command, TG);
                commandbox.setText("");

            }
        }
    }

}
```

**theTurtle Java Class.**

```
public class theTurtle {
    //ArrayList<String> oldCommands = new ArrayList<>();

    public void getCommand(String command, TurtleGraphics TG)
    {
        String[]entries = command.split(" ");
        int var = -1;
        String norm = entries[0];
        if (entries.length == 2)
        {
            var = Integer.parseInt(entries[1]);
        }
        getMethod(norm, var, TG);
    }
    private void getMethod(String command, int var, TurtleGraphics TG)
    {
        if (command.toLowerCase().equals("penup"))
        {
            TG.penUp();
        }
        else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("pendown"))
        {
            TG.penDown();
        }
        else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("turnleft"))
        {
            if (var==-1)
            {
                TG.turnLeft();
            }
            else{
                TG.turnLeft(var);
            }
        }
        else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("turnright"))
        {
            if (var==-1)
            {
                TG.turnRight();
            }
            else{
                TG.turnRight(var);
            }
        }
        else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("forward"))
        {
            if (var == -1 || var <= 0)
            {
                errorEcho(1);
            }
            else{
                TG.forward(var);
            }
        }
        else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("backward"))
        {
            if (var == -1 || var <= 0)
            {
                errorEcho(1);
            }
            else{
                TG.turnRight(180);
                TG.forward(var);
                TG.turnRight(180);
            }
        }
        else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("black"))
        {
            TG.setPenColour(Color.black);
        }
        else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("red"))
        {
            TG.setPenColour(Color.red);
        }
        else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("green"))
        {
            TG.setPenColour(Color.green);
        }
        else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("reset"))
        {
            TG.reset();
            TG.turnLeft(90);
            TG.clear();
            TG.penDown();
        }
        else if (command.toLowerCase().equals("circle"))
        {
            if (var == -1 || var <= 0)
            {
                errorEcho(1);
            }
            else{
                TG.circle(var);
            }
        }
        else{
           myGUI.infoBox("Invalid Command", "ERROR!");
        }

    }
    private void errorEcho(int errorCode)
    {

        myGUI.infoBox("Missing Parameters", "ERROR!");
    }

}
```

[The variables that are show stepping through about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1acic.png)

Comment: Can we see the whole child class?  You may not be extending the parent class properly

Comment: @afghanimah yeah, there you go mate. Sorry.

Comment: It looks OK to me.  I would suggest you step through this code with your debugger, to find out which bits are being run, and which bits aren't.

Comment: It looks rather suspicious to me that you've got a `TurtleGraphics` instance inside a class extending `TurtleGraphics`. Are you sure you don't simply want to use `this` instead of `TG`?

Comment: I would also like to question why your GUI/button is using `TG` and `ETF`, I believe you intend for them to be the same instance?

Comment: Hi thanks everyone. I have added a screenshot with what the variables and such say when running through about, the only thing I can spot is it says 'invalid' in e and ETG but no further explanation?

Comment: To help a bit more, I have added my whole myGUI class just without the imports on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `TurtleGraphics TG = new TurtleGraphics();`
2. Replace `TG` with `this`

This should get you in the right direction.

@Edit

Allright, we do not have the code for TurtleGraphics so we cannot tell 100% but:

First: In your gui calss you define

```
TurtleGraphics TG = new TurtleGraphics();
theTurtle turtle = new theTurtle();
TurtleGraphics ETG = new ExtendedTurtleGraphics();
```

So what you created here has a structure like this

```
TurtleGraphics TG
theTurtle turtle
ExtendedTurtleGraphics ETG {
    TurtleGraphics TG      // You define a new instanct of TurtleGraphics called TG in the ETG object
    theTurle turtle  // You defined a new instance of theTurtle called turtle in the ETG object
}
```

Notice that you now have two turtle obects and two TurtleGraphicsObjects (or actually three because ETG is also an TurtleGraphics as soon as it extends TurtleGraphics)

Allright, then in the "about" function of ExtendedTurtleGraphics you run commands on "turtle" but please be aware that the commands are executed at the following turtle:

```
TurtleGraphics TG
theTurtle turtle
ExtendedTurtleGraphics ETG {
    TurtleGraphics TG    
    theTurle turtle     //  <- this one 
}
```

So basically, the "turtle" you defined in "myGUI" class does not change when you run the "about" method on ETG.
That explains why the console output is working in the about method but you do not see anything happen.

The fix would be to remove the two lines at the MyGui initialization:

```
TurtleGraphics TG = new TurtleGraphics(); // remove this one
theTurtle turtle = new theTurtle();  // remove this one
TurtleGraphics ETG = new ExtendedTurtleGraphics();
```

Then remove this line from ExtendedTurtleGraphics:

```
TurtleGraphics TG = new TurtleGraphics(); // Remove this one
```

In ExtendedTurtleGraphics make theTurtle public.
After this your structure would now look like this:

MyGui:
     ExtendedTurtleGraphic ETG {    // ExtendedTurtleGraphics object is an TurtleGraphic
        theTurle turtle
     }

And now, in myGui class, replace all occurances of "TG" with "ETG" and all occurances of "turtle" with "ETG.turtle"

This means every time you want to to something with the turtle your access the turtle instance from the ETG and and then do it so when you call the "about" method in ExtendedTurtleGraphics you modify the same object.

@Second edit:

Add an Constructor to MyActionListener with argument ETG like this:

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private ExtendedTurtleGraphics ETG;

    public MyActionListener(ExtendedTurtleGraphics ETG){
        this.ETG = ETG;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == commandbox) {

            String command = commandbox.getText();
            isSaved = false;
            ETG.turtle.getCommand(command, ETG);
            commandbox.setText("");

        }
    }
}
```

In MyGui change the Action listener registration like this:

```
commandbox.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(ETG));
```

Comment: Is that in the parent or child class?

Comment: To help a bit more, I have added my whole myGUI class just without the imports on.

Comment: Edited my answer, please check above

Comment: Hi so now I have changed the action listener in myGUI for turtle to ETG.turtle.getCommand(command, ETG), but it says that it cannot resolve turtle. theTurtle is a separate Java class than myGUI and ExtendedTurtleGraphics. theTurtle grabs the command. I have added it to the original post. Sorry for not being clear.

P.S. I really appreciate all of the help.

Comment: "In ExtendedTurtleGraphics make theTurtle public"

Have you done this ?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: in ExtendedTurtleGraphics change ´theTurtle turtle = new theTurtle();´ to ´public theTurtle turtle = new theTurtle();´

By making it public you specify that other classes can read and write this field.
If you don´t specify it they won´t be allowed and you´ll get an error message

Comment: Hi, done that but still says 'Cannot resolve symbol 'turtle'. Thanks.

Comment: So now, it's semi-working. It's running my about() but then running the about() from the original TurtleGraphics.

Comment: It´s actually the other way around and that´s because you call it.
Remove the  "super.about();" from ExtendedTurtleGraphics about() method and you´ll be fine.

Basically the "super" keyword refers to the parent so you call the about() method on the parent and then do the other stuff you defined.

Comment: Thank you, you're an absolute legend!